# ElasticSearch: Providing array in bool should instead of multiple queries

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "match": {
                "uid": "A"
            }
        }, {
            "match": {
                "uid": "B"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Can I provide a list of A,B,C... instead of multiple match sub- queries ?

Comment: You can use `terms` if you want to perform an exact match against your values, but there is no equivalent for `match`

Comment: @Val terms is not working with text type of field. I need exact match only.

Comment: exact match is best performed by using the `keyword` type and `terms`query.

Comment: @Val Thanks for the quick response. This works for me. as UID is mostly constant for me , I have changed the type to keyword and used terms query.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Val in the comments this best works with the `keyword` type. If you want to keep your original mapping, you can store the field in both ways like this:

```
"uid" : {
    "type": "text",
    "fields" : {
        "raw" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can run your `terms`query on the `uid.raw` field.